# Why my matlab executable file takes more time than execution time through matlab command window

Tags: matlab, executable

I have created a executable file using Matlab which runs using MCR but it takes more time in comparison to Matlab command terminal.

Comment: You aren't doing a fair comparison. You should compare the MCR executable to "__starting MATLAB__ _and_ executing the code"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start the executable the first time, the MATLAB runtime is being loaded that can take some seconds. If you start it a second time the runtime should be cached in the RAM and it should run faster like within MATLAB.

Comment: I am measuring execution time using following commands `echo %time%` `myApp.exe` and saving these commands in a batch file named **Myexe.bat** and ran this batch file using command prompt in windows.

Comment: `D:\codes\Matlab>Myexe.bat`

`D:\codes\Matlab>echo 13:04:06.91`
`13:04:06.91`

`D:\codes\Matlab>myApp.exe`
`11-Aug-2015 13:05:26`
`Elapsed time is 12.705512 seconds.`  It is taking almost 80 seconds to run actual program after invocation of exe file.